# Pegar title de Button no React Native?

Tags: react-native

Como eu faço para pegar o valor de title de Button e adicionar em um useState ? Quando clicar no botão eu quero pegar o title dele.

```
<Button
  onPress={onPressLearnMore}
  title="Learn More"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o `title` no `state`. Dessa forma não precisará criar uma referência do componente e nem ter que acessar o DOM com querySelector/getElementBy... do JS Vanilla. Fora que também fica fácil manipular qualquer propriedade do documento posteriormente.

```
const [titleButton, setTitleButton] = useState('Learn More);
```

```
<Button
  onPress={onPressLearnMore}
  title={titleButton}
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
```

Assim fica muito mais fácil manipulá-lo.
Ou você pode optar pelo trabalhoso e não tão bonito jeito de guardar o componente em uma variável e resgatar as suas props, por exemplo:

```
const meuBotao = (
  <Button title="Meu título" onPress={onPressMeuBotao} />
);

function onPressMeuBotao() {
  console.log(meuBotao.props.title);
}
```